# How can i return array of object from web service with c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services

I want to write simple web service return to user array object string with c#,write this code in server web service:

```
public string[] mymethod()
{
    string [] mytemp=new string[10];
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        mytemp[i]=i+1.toString();

    }
    return mytemp;
}
```

that's code return to me this output:
[image]

but i want return this:

```
<myMethodResult>
        <string>
            <name>user1</name>
        </string>
        <string>
            <name>user2</name>
        </string>
        <string>
            <name>user3</name>
        </string>
 </myMethodResult>
```

Comment: What web service are you using? ASP.NET Web API? WCF? ASMX?

Comment: @BonMacalindong i use the asmx.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just return that xml structure without informing the web service the type you want to return. Basically you need to create a class that has a [Serializable] attribute and then add properties which will resemble the result you're expecting and that class is the one you will return on your web method. You may refer to this Microsoft [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/564k8ys4(v=vs.110).aspx)